# Disable Resharper's "Adjust namespace" for specific files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, resharper

I have a class with a namespace not matching the folder structure of the project.

With `// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace` I can disable the hint that the namespace does not correspond to the file-location. But when Refactoring the Projects namespaces, the class is still selected for adjusting the namespace.

Is there a way to disable the adjust namespace?

---

Update with sample:

In my case I have a view class that has to be in the `System.Web.Mvc`-Namespace. 
The file location is [Root]>src>Views
The default namespace of the Root-Project is `Com.xxxxx.Commons.Web`

So Resharper always wants to adjust the namespace to either
`Com.xxxxx.Commons.Web.Views` or to `Com.xxxxx.Commons.Web` if I disable the namespace-provider-flag für the Views folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a long existing [bug in R#](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-337420) that `disable CheckNamespace` isn't respected by the "Adjust namespaces" refactoring. As I know, there is no other way to exclude specific files from this refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to that bug. Your answer is deprecated now. I've posted an updated answer because I thought that was the correct thing to do [(see this meta post)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated). Also, I'm just letting you know that ReSharper has fixed this bug, in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the folder as a Namespace Provider by opening the properties window (right click -> properties) for the folder you wish to exclude and change Namespace Provider to false.

Comment: I knew of this "trick". Unfortunatly this does not work if the namespace is completly different to the file location. I updated the question with my case.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper's Adjust Namespace refactoring no longer affects namespaces marked with `// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace`. The [long-existing bug in ReSharper](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-337420) *(link referenced in @ulrichb's old answer)* has been fixed in ReSharper 2016.2.

---

**Limitations** (currently, as of ReSharper 2018.1)

- If there is no namespace at all, ReSharper will automatically add a namespace even if `disable CheckNamespace` is specified for that file.

For example, this works:

```
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace DoNotAdjustThisNamespace
{
    public class TestClass1
    {
    }
}
```

However, this does not:

```
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
public class TestClass1
{
}
```

- There is still a misleading UI issue where all files still appear in the Adjust Namespace UI, but the namespace changes will not actually take place. This is a bit misleading..

Comment: I have tested this but am not seeing the behavior you described. My files are still having their namespaces adjusted.

Comment: @Lopsided It looks like I observed this behaviour on 2018.1. The issue tracker currently says the bug re-surfaced in 2018.2, and that is was fixed in 2019.2. If you're still having issues on the latest version, perhaps you can report it to JetBrains.